# How to have arabic numerals in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I am new to Ubuntu and I  have a problem with LibreOffice Writer. When I use Arabic language, the numbers remain in Latin, how can I fix this problem?

thanks;

Comment: 0123 are Arabic (not latin) digits used in North Africa, ٠١٢٣ are Arabic-Indic digits used in Middle East. See Wikipedia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to:

> Tools > Options > Language settings > Complex text layout

Then choose context or Hindi instead of Arabic. Then your problem should be fixed.